# Issues with Apache HTTPD 2.4 LocationMatch containint?

Tags: apache-2.4

I am having trouble using a LocationMatch for a specific site that contains a ?

My current LocationMatch is
<LocationMatch "^/SOME/FOLDER/STRUCTURE/TEST/?cmd=logout">

The actual URL contains the ?, but I am having trouble getting this specific locationmatch to work.

The error that I get is
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /etc/httpd/htdocs, referer: https://URL/SOME/FOLDER/STRUCTURE/TEST/?cmd=logout

Comment: you can not use query string in a location match. Also consider checking permissions to your documentroot. It would be better if you document better everything you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As ezra-s said, the query string, that is the part of the URL after the `?`, isn't part of the location that's matched. So you have to test it separately, with something like

```
<Location /SOME/FOLDER/STRUCTURE/TEST>
  <If "%{QUERY_STRING} == cmd=logout">
  ...
  </If>
</Location>
```

That works to match the whole query string. But if `cmd=logout` may only be part of a longer query string, then you'll need a more general condition using regular expressions, something like

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(^|&)cmd=logout(&|$)/">
```

See [Expression parser](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) for information about the `If` condition, including an example that uses `QUERY_STRING`.